# Draw rectangles with javascript that have an text inputboxes inside

Tags: javascript, canvas, input

I have two inputs number of rows and number of columns and a button which runs a function that shows/draws  rectangles equal too the number of rows and columns [rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erG9y.png)

I would like to have two input boxes inside each of the rectangles, how do I do this? I have used canvas to show the rectangles and from what I have read you can't use canvas and input together.

Comment: _"and from what I have read you can't use canvas and input together"_ - to phrase it in a way that makes a bit more sense: Canvas does not allow for any sort of "user input". You will need to use text input fields for this - placed _over_ your canvas, in the correct positions.

Comment: Instead of using canvas to create the rectangles. You could use divs and set the div's border to create the rectangle. Then you can easily put input boxes inside the rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you stick to HTML to build your layout. You can use CSS features like grid and flexbox to create the desired effect.

Here's an example of how you can build your UI in plain javascript. If you feel the code is getting complex rather quickly, you could explore one of the many UI frameworks out there that abstract away the creation of the HTML.

In the example below:

- Outline the core of your UI in HTML:

  - Number inputs for row and column count
  - A "show" button to confirm input changes
  - A wrapper for your grid
  - A template for your grid cell
- Define styles that never change in CSS, e.g.:

  - The black outline of your cells
  - The basic configuration of the grid
- Implement the grid creation in javascript and attach it to your inputs and button

  - Calculate the required number of cells
  - Create or delete cells based on any new requirement
  - Update the `grid-template-columns` property of the wrapper to ensure the correct layout.

```js
const show = () => {
  const [ rowInput, colInput ] = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
  const template = document.querySelector("template");
  
  const rowCount = rowInput.valueAsNumber;
  const colCount = colInput.valueAsNumber;
  const cellCount = rowCount * colCount;
  
  // Update col and row props
  grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${colCount}, 1fr)`;

  // Ensure box count matches
  while (grid.children.length > cellCount) {
    grid.removeChild(grid.lastChild);
  }
  
  while (grid.children.length < cellCount) {
    grid.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}

document
  .querySelector("button")
  .addEventListener("click", show);
  
show();
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.cell {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<label>Rows:<input type="number" value="2" min="1" max="10" step="1"></label>
<label>Cols:<input type="number" value="3" min="1" max="10" step="1"></label>
<button>Show</button>  

<div class="grid">

</div>

<template>
  <div class="cell">
    <input type="text"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test this. My goal is to make it look like [this](https://imgur.com/a/0A8TLLP) with one input in each of the small squares and two inputs in the rectangles